# Gensim Dictionary slows down drastically whilst making

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, gensim

I have 26,000,000 tweets and am creating a Gensim Dictionary with them. The first approach:

```py
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

corpus = []
with open(input_file, "r") as file:
    for row in file:
        comment = json.loads(row)        
        corpus.append(comment['text'].split())

gdict = Dictionary(corpus)
```

Takes about an hour just for the final line. I have also tried the following:

```py
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

gdict = Dictionary()
with open(input_file, "r") as file:
    for row in file:
        comment = json.loads(row)        
        gdict.add_documents([comment['text'].split()])
```

This takes 2 minutes to process the first 11,400,000 tweets, and then suddenly slows down, and predicts over 3000 hours to finish.

I have randomised the order of the tweets and the same happens after around the same number of tweets, so it isn't a particular tweet doing it.

I have also grouped the tweets into various batch sizes before using `add_documents` and the same issue happens for all of them, around the same stage.

With the first approach, the final size of gdict is 1.4mb so it isn't a size issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: How large is the source file? In case where the processing finished (after an hour on the final line), how many unique entries were in the finished dictionary (`len(gdict)`)? How much RAM does the system have, and if you watch measures of RAM & virtual-memory ("swap") usage during the run, is the slowdown correlated with the point that all physical RAM is exhausted – & thus heavy use of virtual-memory begins? Is any virtual-memory backed by a spinning hard drive or an SSD? How did you estimate the final `gdict` size as 1.4MB? (That doesn't seem enough for all unique tokens in 26M tweets!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the questions I asked in a comment are all relevant for diagnosing a general slowdown in this sort of process, looking at the `gensim.corpora.Dictionary` source, I see another likely culprit for the problem: a rather inefficient & oft-repeated 'pruning', once the `Dictionary` has 2M entries.

If you have sufficient RAM, supplying a much larger `prune_at` parameter to either the contructor (when you're also passing the `corpus` in) or the `.add_documents()` call (when you're using that) should forestall or eliminate the issue. Ideally, you'd pick a `prune_at` value larger than the `Dictionary` ever becomes, so pruning never happens – though that risks exhausting memory, if your corpus has more unique words than can be tracked in RAM.

(Side note: if your `comment['text']` fields haven't been preprocessed in any way, then a simple `.split()` tokenization will likely leave you with lots of extra tokens like words connected to surrounding punctuation or with varying capitalization - which would inflate the token count a lot, and perhaps be less useful for many downstream tasks.)

Comment: You are exactly right. For some reason, passing `prune_at = None` when creating the dictionary, still has the same issue. However, adding that parameter in `add_documents` works perfectly - thank you!